# React-infinite-scroll component not loading after initial data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, trpc.io

I've encountered a rather frustrating bug where I at one point had the react-infinite-scroll component working properly and all was well, but while doing some styling I noticed that now it's only showing 'Loading...' and not loading in the next batch of data anymore.

```
 const getAllItemsInfinite = api.items.getAllItemsInfinite.useInfiniteQuery(
    { householdId },
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage.nextCursor,
    }
  );
```

```
<InfiniteScroll
                dataLength={
                  getAllItemsInfinite.data?.pages.flatMap((page) => page.items)
                    .length ?? 0
                }
                next={getAllItemsInfinite.fetchNextPage}
                hasMore={!!getAllItemsInfinite.hasNextPage}
                loader={
                  <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "1rem" }}>
                    Loading...
                  </h4>
                }
                endMessage={
                  getAllItemsInfinite.data?.pages[0]?.items.length !== 0 &&
                  !getAllItemsInfinite.isLoading && (
                    <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                      <b>End of items.</b>
                    </p>
                  )
                }
              >
                <div
                  className={cn(
                    "m-2 flex  flex-wrap justify-center gap-1 3xl:mx-auto ",
                    {
                      "m-4 gap-4": showingItemCards,
                    }
                  )}
                >
                  {getAllItemsInfinite.isSuccess &&
                    getAllItemsInfinite.data?.pages
                      .flatMap((page) => page.items)
                      .filter((item) => {
                        if (debouncedValue === "") {
                          return item;
                        } else if (
                          item.name
                            .toLowerCase()
                            .includes(debouncedValue.toLowerCase()) ||
                          item.brand
                            ?.toLowerCase()
                            .includes(debouncedValue.toLowerCase())
                        ) {
                          return item;
                        }
                      })
                      .map((item) =>
                        showingItemCards ? (
                          <ItemCard key={item.id} {...item} />
                        ) : (
                          <Item key={item.id} {...item} />
                        )
                      )}
                </div>
              </InfiniteScroll>
```

and here is the backend function:

```
const limit = 10;

 getAllItemsInfinite: protectedProcedure
    .input(
      z.object({
        cursor: z.string().nullish(),
        householdId: z.string(),
      })
    )
    .query(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const { cursor, householdId } = input;
      const items = await ctx.prisma.item.findMany({
        cursor: cursor ? { id: cursor } : undefined,
        take: limit + 1,
        orderBy: {
          name: "asc",
        },
        where: {
          householdId,
        },
      });
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises
      items.forEach(async (item) => {
        if (item.expirationDate !== null) {
          const totalDays = calculateDaysUntilExpiry(item.expirationDate);

          await ctx.prisma.item.update({
            where: { id: item.id },
            data: {
              daysUntilExpiry: totalDays,
            },
          });

          if (totalDays < 0 && item.expired === false) {
            await ctx.prisma.item.update({
              where: { id: item.id },
              data: {
                expired: true,
              },
            });
          }
        }
      });

      let nextCursor: typeof cursor | undefined = undefined;
      if (items.length > limit) {
        const nextItem = items.pop(); // return the last item from the array
        if (nextItem) nextCursor = nextItem?.id;
      }
      return {
        items,
        nextCursor,
      };
    }),
```

Sorry for the length of the code but I didn't want to chop the function up incase I missed something pertinent to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing it was tied to the height of the parent div of the infinite scroll component, I was to fix it by adding the scrollableTarget prop which I passed the id of the parent div, found here:

[React InfiniteScroll in a scrollable component on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59689791/react-infinitescroll-in-a-scrollable-component-on-the-page)